# Mule - how to use enumeration in groovy scripts?

Tags: mule

In mule 3.8.3 how can we use enumeration in groovy scripts? The official documentation does not explain it in detail and there is not a direct example on this. Tutorials found online are not up to date. If not enumeration what is the expected way of handling constants in mule flows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the documentation or an example dedicated to this topic but from some examples we can see an example on `service orchestration choice routing usage` :

The steps are is basically

1. add the file to your source, I mean to src/main/java folder of the project, preferably in a package as `org.myorg.example`.

and let the type definition in Java be as follows

```
     public enum MyEnum {

         SUCCESS, FAIL;
      }
```

2. Use it in your script like this

   ```
       <scripting:component doc:name="Set Process Properties">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[    

           message.setInvocationProperty("responseCode", org.myorg.example.MyEnum.SUCCESS)  

        ]]></scripting:script></scripting:component>
   ```

If you had properties in your enum

```
     public enum MyEnum {

        SUCCESS("S"), FAIL("F");
        private String code;
        //getter, setter, toString etc 
        ...
      }
```

You can use it like

```
     org.myorg.example.MyEnum.SUCCESS.code
```

You can get a full example from here Mule exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of groovy.

```
enum MyColors{
  BLUE, RED, WHITE
}
println MyColors.values()
```

Will output

```
[BLUE, RED, WHITE]
```

Comment: I was asking how to use it particularly in Mule flows.